# Linux redirected output not print to the end but the middle of file

Tags: java, linux, stdout, stderr

This are the startup command:

```java
nohup java $options -jar foo.jar > foo.log 2>&1 &
```

the output like this:

```
...
2020-11-26 21:27:23,577 INFO ...
2020-11-26 21:27:23,577 INFO ...
2020-11-23 12:41:55,783 INFO ...
2020-11-23 12:41:55,783 INFO ...
...
```

Several rows start with `2020-11-23` always at the end of file. If java output more, the file will become:

```
2020-11-26 21:27:23,577 INFO ...
2020-11-26 21:27:23,577 INFO ...
[The New Row]
2020-11-23 12:41:55,783 INFO ...
2020-11-23 12:41:55,783 INFO ...
```

The lines in the end always those lines, you can affirm this by dates and times.

### Update With Answer

This is what my script look like:

```
...
kill $fooPid
nohup java $options -jar foo.jar > foo.log 2>&1 &
...
```

The `kill` won't kill the program immidiatelly, that's mean there could be **2 programs write into the same file in the same time**.

For that, I added `sleep 0.5` between the 2 commands.

```
...
kill $fooPid
sleep 0.5
nohup java $options -jar foo.jar > foo.log 2>&1 &
...
```

Then the problem fixed.

Also, You can use `kill -9 $fooPid` to kill the former program immidiatelly.

(I still dont't know why the lines came from former program always in the end, but that doesn't matter now)

Comment: To be clear, did you observe the file in the initial state **and then** a line later appeared in the middle?  Or is this a  matter of lines not appearing in the order they were emitted by the program?  For the latter, I'd guess that it's because stdout and stderr are getting independently flushed to the file.

Comment: The former one. The lines in the end always those lines, you can affirm this by the dates and times.  @user14644949

Comment: I can't imagine how that happens, then.  It can't be just a case of writing into the middle of the file - you'd have to intentionally shuffle lines down the file to make room. I assume (as shown in your example) than no lines were overwritten?

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

```
start program > log
...
kill $pid
start program > log
```

The 2nd started process will replace the log file. If the former process hasn't been killed, it may now write log to the new log file. But the later process know nothing about this, it will write to the log file from position 0.

*Inspired by https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346196*